# I keep getting an <identifier> expected error

Tags: java, error-handling

I get an `<identifier>` expected error while trying to run this code:

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

    public static double aiChoice() {
        return Math.random();
    }

    System.out.println(aiChoice);
}
```

Comment: Is this Java? Can you paste here your whole class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have System.out.println(aiChoice); outside any methods and try to print a method without calling it. Instead, put your `System.out.println` into the `main` method, like this:

```
public static void main(String [ ] args) {
    System.out.println(RockPaperScissors.aiChoice());
}
```

Note the parantheses after `aiChoice`, making sure that you call the method. If your main method does not know about the `RockPaperScrissors` `class`, then make sure to

```
import RockPaperScrissors;
```

at the start of the file where you have your `main` method.